# pandas retrieve the frequency of a time series

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to retrieve the frequency of a time series in pandas?

```
rng = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts =pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
```

ts.frequency or ts.period are not methods available.

Thanks

**Edit:**
Can we infer the frequency from time series that do not specify frequency?

```
import pandas.io.data as web
aapl = web.get_data_yahoo("AAPL")

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-01-04 00:00:00, ..., 2013-12-19 00:00:00]
Length: 999, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Can we somehow can the aapl's frequency? As we know, it's business days.

Comment: this would be not None if it was a regular frequency. it is NOT business days as holidays are excluded.

Comment: for your last question, freq I can't correctly define freq, so don't know what to suggest.

Comment: That's true. Stock returns do exclude holidays. I will start the new question for what I truly want to achieve.

Comment: @zsljulius remember that an abritrary other day can be exclueded as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For `DatetimeIndex`

```
>>> rng
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2011-01-03 23:00:00]
Length: 72, Freq: H, Timezone: None
>>> len(rng)
72
>>> rng.freq
<1 Hour>
>>> rng.freqstr
'H'
```

Similary for series indexed with this index

```
>>> ts.index.freq
<1 Hour>
```

Comment: Thanks Alko, what about Timeseries? Just updated my question.

Comment: @zsljulius you have your rng as index, so you can use `ts.index.freq`

Comment: thanks! What about those time series that does not have frequency specified? Can we somehow infer the frequency? I will give an example in my question.

Comment: @zsljulius I don't think it's ok to update question indefinitely, I'd reccomend starting a new one.

Comment: Haha, because I think they are related, that's we I kinda group them together in this one question. I promise this is the last question

Comment: @zsljulius this last is not so well defined as previous, as generally yahoo finance data can have nontrivial distribution of days (excl holidays, some shutdown events etc)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43623/discussion-between-zsljulius-and-alko)

Answer (score 29):

To infer the frequency, just use the built-in function [`infer_freq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.infer_freq.html)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.infer_freq(ts.index)
```

Comment: This works fine contrary to FaCoffee's comment. (Though of course the code snipped of sweetdream is incomplete because of the undefined ts.)

Comment: Should be accepted, but it should be noted that it will fail if index is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

@sweetdream 's answer is pretty good actually, because frequency of the data is not always kept as an attribute to the index, so this won't work if it isn't specified:

```
df.index.freq
```

@sweetdream mentioned the infer_freq solution, which leads to another day that I'm again amazed by Pandas, that infers the frequency by looking at the index. But sometimes it doesn't work, and there are another way of finding.

Both should work:

```
text_freq_of_hourly_data_infer_freq = pd.infer_freq(df.index)
text_freq_of_hourly_data_inferred_freq = df.index.inferred_freq
```

They should both return `'H'`, but if dataframe is not sorted, it will fail on inferring and it will return `None` as it is stated on documentation. So you should sort the index.

And don't forget to give "index" to it, not the dataframe, it can infer from the column instead of index if it's specified, again documentation tells, in the index.

> If passed a Series will use the values of the series (NOT THE INDEX).

References:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.inferred_freq.html?highlight=infer_freq

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.infer_freq.html?highlight=infer_freq

Answer (score 0):

If your index is **datetime64** but it has no frequency associated, None is returned when using the above mentioned methods.

I propose a rudimentary methodology for just **aproximate** the index frequency:

Being ts a pandas.Series:

```
abs(np.diff(ts)).mean()
```