# How to determine the frequency of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which represents time series. I would to find a way to find the frequency of the data (daily, weekly, monthly…)
Is there a way to do it in pandas ?

I mean I have a time series with index equal to

```
DatetimeIndex(['2011-07-07', '2011-07-14', '2011-07-21', '2011-07-28',
               '2011-08-04', '2011-08-11', '2011-08-18', '2011-08-25',
               '2011-09-01', '2011-09-08',
               ...
               '2023-01-05', '2023-01-12', '2023-01-19', '2023-01-26',
               '2023-02-02', '2023-02-09', '2023-02-16', '2023-02-23',
               '2023-03-02', '2023-03-09'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=582, freq=None)
```

from my point of view it is weekly data but I would like to get it from a code line (also it could be daily, monthly...

Comment: Please provide some sample/programable data, what you have tried, and what the expected results are.

Comment: You can try subtracting the time values and checking the timedelta values

Comment: Does `pd.infer_freq(df.index)` work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030322/530160

Comment: No pd.infer_freq(df.index) return None whereas it should be weekly from my point of view

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help you !

#### Code

```py
import pandas as pd

date_rng = pd.to_datetime(['2011-07-07', '2011-07-14', '2011-07-21', '2011-07-28', 
                           '2011-08-04', '2011-08-11', '2011-08-18', '2011-08-25', 
                           '2011-09-01', '2011-09-08']) # DatetimeIndex

freq = pd.infer_freq(date_rng)
print(freq)
```

#### Output

```
W-THU
```

`W-THU`:

- Frequency string used to represent a time series frequency in Pandas
- It represents every Thursday at weekly intervals
- `W` stands for `weekly`
- `THU` is the abbreviation for `Thursday`