# Correctly formatting a datetime index when reading in a csv file Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have an hourly time series data set for a full year. The date column in the original csv file is formatted as 'day.month.year' as the snippet below shows.

```
0       01.01.2018 00:00
1       01.01.2018 01:00
2       01.01.2018 02:00
3       01.01.2018 03:00
4       01.01.2018 04:00
      
8759    31.12.2018 23:00
```

My usual approach to reading in the csv file and converting the date column into a datetime index  is as follows;

```
date_cols = ["time_stamp"] 
df = pd.read_csv('path/analysis.csv', sep = ';', index_col = 'time_stamp', parse_dates = date_cols)
```

Using this approach, the index is now converted to a datetime index

```
type(df.index)
Out[85]: pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

However, when I double check the dates in python, I notice a couple of things.

**1**. Format is now different compared than the format in the csv file.

**original format**: day.month.year

**new format**: year-day-month

**2**. Furthermore, the new format is not consistent as it frequently switches from '*year-day-month*' to '*year-month-day*'. The example below shows the format switch from the Jan 2 to Jan 14

Here the dates are formatted as *year-day-month*

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-01 01:00:00', '2018-02-01 02:00:00',
               '2018-02-01 03:00:00', '2018-02-01 04:00:00',
               '2018-02-01 05:00:00', '2018-02-01 06:00:00',
               '2018-02-01 07:00:00', '2018-02-01 08:00:00',
               '2018-02-01 09:00:00', '2018-02-01 10:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time_stamp', freq=None)
```

It then switches to *year-month-day*

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-14 00:00:00', '2018-01-14 01:00:00',
               '2018-01-14 02:00:00', '2018-01-14 03:00:00',
               '2018-01-14 04:00:00', '2018-01-14 05:00:00',
               '2018-01-14 06:00:00', '2018-01-14 07:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time_stamp', freq=None)
```

Is there a way of resolving this, so my date format is consistent over the entire dataset? I don't mind that the dates are formatted differently from my original formatting (i.e., point 1), but as long as it remains consistent.

**3**. I noticed that pandas does not recognise the frequency of the dataset, which is in hours

Would appreciate any assistance to resolve the issues above. Thanks

Comment: 1) that's just a matter of display. Once you read the csv and parse the dates, you no longer have string but datetime data type. datetime dtype has not format, it's a binary data structure. What you see is it's string representation. 2) pandas parses "month first" by default. If your input is "day first" for instance, you'll need to specify that (kwarg `dayfirst=True`). 3) See maybe [pandas retrieve the frequency of a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20711180/10197418).

Comment: ok, what about the switch in formatting (point 2). Is this normal behavior in pandas?

Comment: If your input format (csv) has the day first, set `dayfirst=True` in the call to `read_csv`. That *should* prevent the "switching". Better double-check that or [parse the datetime strings](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) *after* you load the csv, with a specific `format`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the dayfirst = True argument and it works. However, when I query the frequency using pd.infer_freq(df), I don't get an output

Comment: Not sure about the freq. Did you check the (unique) diffs of your datetimeindex? Is it only 1 hour?

Comment: I tried checking unique diffs in the datetime index and i get `dtype: timedelta64[ns]`, which is strange since the entire dataset is on an hourly frequency.  I then tried manually defining the format as `df = df.asfreq('H')`, which seems to do the trick. A better approach would be appreciated

Comment: timedelta is the expected dtype. running `df.index.to_series().diff().dropna().unique()` should give something like `['0 days 01:00:00']` in case you only have 1 hour differences between the entries.